# PowerPoint web app error when launching into view mode from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office365, powerpoint

We are getting an error from PowerPoint web app when launching into view mode from SharePoint 2010.

Error message:
Title - MicroSoft PowerPoint web app
Message - Either network connectivity has been lost or the server is too busy to service your request. Check your network connection and try the request later.

This happens on some but not all PowerPoint PPT files. I can resolve the issue buy making copy of the file and deleting the original and then replacing with the copy.

I have checked the SharePoint log files and get a time out error at approximately the same time as I try and open the file.

Opening to edit in the web app is ok and opening in the desktop application is also working.

Has anyone seen this and found a solution? Thanks...